# Unable to start PCF Dev instance

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

Im facing a weird issue when I try to start pcf dev on my local machine.
[image]

As you can see that whenever I try to start it fails at the step where its trying to add a dvd drive.
My cf version is 6.38.0+7ddf0aadd.2018-08-07

My cf dev version is 0.0.9

Total system memory 8.0GB
Windows 10 with Hyper-V

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you found this out [here](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/pcfdev/issues/347), but PCF Dev currently fails when a user directory has a space in it. This is a [known bug](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/pcfdev/issues/346), which will hopefully be fixed soon.

If you do the following you can work around this limitation:

```
$ cf dev stop # to clean any leftover resources
$ $env:CFDEV_HOME="C:\cfdev"
$ cf dev start -f E:\pcfdev-pas.v.2.0.20.0-build.0.82.0.iso
```

This just puts the directory for PCF Dev resources into a location that has no spaces.

Comment: Yeah I asked this question here and raised the issue in github, expecting the answer from any one place :)

Comment: Github Issues is the best place to ask questions on PCF Dev. It's a straight line to the devs. I don't know if they monitor SO. That's why I updated this. At least there will be an answer for anyone else that comes across this.

Comment: True, will be helpful for future reference. Marking this as correct answer